# No matching results for a unique query (error 782)

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api, objectdb

This code keeps throwing an error because there aren't any values present in the database:

```
public Foo getFoo(Parent p1, Parent p2) {
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Foo> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Foo.class);
    Root<Foo> root = criteriaQuery.from(Foo.class);
    criteriaQuery.select(root).where(criteriaBuilder.and(
            criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("p1"), entityManager.find(Parent.class, p1)),
            criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("p2"), entityManager.find(Parent.class, p2))
    ));
    return entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getSingleResult();
}
```

I would prefer if it just returned a null object though. Is there a way that I can do this?

Exception gets thrown on this line:

`Foo foo = fooDao.getFoo(p1, p2);`

> [ObjectDB 2.5.7_03] javax.persistence.NoResultException No matching
>   results for a unique query (error 782)    at
>   com.objectdb.jpa.JpaQuery.getSingleResult(JpaQuery.java:754)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getResultList` instead of `getSingleResult`.

See:

http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/execute

Answer (score 1):

Catch the exception and return null.